# Dragging element next to other draggable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to move all my `<p>` elements, at the moment works fine but while I was testing I saw an issue, when I drag one element next to the other sometimes I'm not able to drag the first element again, I create this example for you:

```js
 $(function () {
   $(".draggable").draggable();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-md-12">
  <p class="draggable">Drag me to the other div+</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <p class="draggable">Hello!</p>
</div>
```

Just try to drag the elements like in this image:

[Dragging problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlZXL.png)

Because it's jQueryUI code I do not post it. So my question is, what could be the problem and how can I solve it? Maybe I'm missing properties or something but I'm new using jQueryUI, thanks in advance.

[CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjdBmX)

Answer (score 0):

`<p>`'s have 100% width, so the second one is over the first one in the old said position. Add borders or bg to see that.

Now, the `p` is under the `div` (can't be moved by same reason). Add `z-index`>0 to make the `p` over any `div`:

Solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGLOEm

Comment: I see... and what about [http://imgur.com/a/he7XC](this...) putting below persist the issue

Comment: Add borders to them to be able to see them. Now I cant see ther pos/size